# fs.writefile is making POST request loop infinitly within my express app

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, fs

I have this current server code:

```
const express = require("express")
const fs = require("fs")
const router = express.Router()
const path = require("path")

const todos = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../db", "todolist.json"), "utf8"))

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(todos)
})

router.post("/new", async (req, res) => {
    const { title, description } = req.body

    const todoItem = {
        id: "3",
        title,
        description
    }

    todos.todos.push(todoItem)

    const data = JSON.stringify(todos, null, 2)

    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../db", "todolist.json"), data, () => {}) 
    res.status(201).json(todoItem)
})
```

client:

```
console.log("Hello world!")

const somedata = {
    title: "A new boy",
    description: "Recieved from the client"
}

const main = async () => {
    const response1 = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/todo", {
        method: "GET",
    })
    const data1 = await response1.json()

    const response2 = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/todo/new", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(somedata), 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    })

    const data2 = await response2.json()

    return { data1, data2 }
}

main().then(data => console.log(data))
```

When I make a /POST request to create a new entity the browser just loops the request over and over until I manually have to quit the server. This does not happen if I use postman for some reason. Does anybody see any obvious error here with how the writeFile-method is used and why it continuously reloads the browser to keep pushing POST requests?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Is there something missing in the server code you posted?  It only shows a `/` get route and a `/todo` post route.  But, the client code shows a GET to /todo and a POST to /todo/new?

Comment: I am using the express router functionality, in the server.js (which is not included here), you can specify the routes like this but that is not part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem! And it took me about 1 hour to understand what my Problem is:

If you use "live server extension", the server will restart everytime, when you write, change or delete a file in the project folder!

**So, if your node-app wirte a file, the live-server will restart and the app writes the file again! => loop**

In my case, i write a pdf-file. All i had to do, is to tell the live server extension to ignore pdf files:

So i just add to "settings.json":

> "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles":["**/*.pdf"]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `fs.writeFileSync()` or write some code in its callback

Comment: I tried that as well but did not work unfortunately. Both writefilesync and writefile with or without callbacks does not work, they both loop the browser to refresh and make new post request indefinately. This does not happen if I use some other kind of client, like postman, then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.writeFile` is asynchronous function. So, to send a response `after` file written you must do it in the callback. And of course, don't forget about error checking. I.e.

```js
router.post("/new", async (req, res) => {
    const { title, description } = req.body

    const todoItem = {
        id: "3",
        title,
        description
    }

    todos.todos.push(todoItem)

    const data = JSON.stringify(todos, null, 2)

    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../db", "todolist.json"), data, (err) => {
   if(err) {
       throw err;
    }
   res.status(201).json(todoItem)
  }) 
 })
```

Or you can use `fs.writeFileSync` as [Muhammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10616029/muhammad) mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried both solutions and they did not help :( there was no error returned from the callback and using the syncronous method did not change it even though i thought so initially

Comment: Ok, I will try to reproduce your issue and will get back to you

Comment: Note that my server is on PORT 3000, while my client is on PORT 5500 live server extension (using cors to transfer the request through), but that should not make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. It seemed that the live server extension was messing things up when I had the client and server on separate ports, making the browser refresh for every request made somehow. I switched back to them sharing port, which then makes it work. I have to find a good way of separating them on a later basis  without this bug happening, but that is for another time.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yeah, hot reloading does not always work as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I share my working sample.body-parser dependency is need to get body in post request.Please don't change the order in server.js.Check and let me know.
and also check once whether your client code is in in loop.

My server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const fs = require("fs")
const router = express.Router()
const path = require("path")
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const todos = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../db", "todolist.json"), "utf8"))

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/",router)
router.get("/todo", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(todos)
})

router.post("/todo/new", async (req, res) => {
    const { title, description } = req.body
    const todoItem = {
        id: "3",
        title,
        description
    }

    todos.todos.push(todoItem)
    const data = JSON.stringify(todos, null, 2)
    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../db", "todolist.json"), data, () => {})
    res.status(201).json(todoItem)
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server running in Port`);
});
```

todolist.json

```
{
  "todos": []
}
```